# What else is needed to use gitlab 7.1.1 external smtp email settings?

Tags: email, smtp, settings, gitlab

I know that, to use smtp in gitlab 7.1.1, you need the following config; In:

```
/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml
```

edit following line

```
## Email settings
# Email address used in the "From" field in mails sent by GitLab
email_from: account@your-mail-server.com
```

and rename this file

```
/home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb.sample
```

to

```
/home/git/gitlab/config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb
```

and edit following settings:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
address: "email.server.com",
port: 456,
user_name: "smtp",
password: "123456",
domain: "gitlab.company.com",
authentication: :login,
enable_starttls_auto: true
}
```

and restart GitLab instance.

Is there other points you need to be aware in order to use smtp-based email with GitLab 7.x?

Answer (score 5):

Note that:

- `config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb` has been added to `.gitignore` only recently (GitLab 7.0+, [PR 7062](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/pull/7062), [commit a727d25](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/a727d25eee91ac4a5ef4f6dc2ec63b073439758d))
- [issue 6023](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6023) does mention:

> Gitlab uses the **system configured `sendmail`** to issue emails to users.
>   **The recommended method is to configure your host sendmail so that it properly works and then Gitlab will successfully email as a result**.
>
> **If configuring `sendmail` is not desirable, then Gitlab provides `smtp_settings.rb`** which can be used to override default Gitlab email settings.
>   This uses ruby `net::smtp` to configure email.
>   In order to properly configure it one must know the available SMTP AUTH methods allowed by their mail provider. `ruby net::smtp` supports only three auth schemes: `PLAIN`, `LOGIN`, and `CRAM MD5`.

- [issue 6845](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/6845) reminds us:

> If you're using SMTP, make sure you change:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

> to

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

> in the `config/environments/production.rb` file.